# CSS div and image opacity effect

Tags: html, css, hover

The following code shows the image in the div tag.

```
<div class='item'>
        <img class='img' src="image1.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

I am using the following css to add effects to the html image code:

```
img{
width:50px;
height:50px;
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);

}

img:hover{
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

I am using this to have opacity effects in css. With this code, the opacity effect works well when I hover over the image itself. But how do I make it so that the opacity effect on the image occurs when I hover over the div tag instead. I want to be able to hover over any part of the item div which encapsulated the image, to get the change opacity effect on the image. NB effect on just the image not the entire div. Can this be done in css? If so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
img:hover{
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

to

```
.item:hover img{
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

This will change the opacity of the `img` when the div is in `hover` state.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery for this then I think this will be easy

```
 $('.item').hover(function(){ $('.img').css('opacity','1.0');}, function(){ $('.img').css('opacity','0.4');});
```

I assume you know jquery. You can't use :hover pseudo class of CSS over elements that don't have href attribute according to Sitepoint.